# Canon MP240 does not work in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, printing, printer, canon-pixma

I recently installed Ubuntu 12.04 in place of Windows XP on my parent's computer. I used the Printing dialog from System Settings to install the printer. I was able to successfully print a Test Page, and so I thought that was the end of that.
However, after receiving numerous complaints from my clients about the printer not working I did some investigating. The printer acts really strangely under Ubuntu.

- The printer does not have issues with printing a Test Page from the Printer Properties window
- It will print word documents (LibreOffice) on occasion; if it doesn't work the status of the print job remains as Pending/Processing, or if it begins to print but fails the paper just gets stuck halfway and the only way to get the paper out is to do a power cycle on the printer (unplug from the wall, because pressing the power button doesn't do anything)
- It has never even attempted to print any PDF print jobs, whether it is submitted from a PDF viewer or from the browser
- Everything works fine when the printer is connected to a Windows computer

I am no Linux guru, but if you need more info I will be happy to provide it to you.

Comment: Download the `deb` driver from [here](http://software.canon-europe.com/products/0010645.asp) and install it.

Comment: @Cornelius After an excruciating install process (it wasn't as simple as running the `deb` files, unfortunately) the printer seems to work now. All the posts I found regarding the drivers were for Ubuntu v10... it's strange the issue hasn't been taken care of by now. Thanks for the assistance!

Comment: valsidalv - It looks like you got your problem solved.  For the benefit of others with the same issue (and people who think you might still need a solution), could you summarize the solution in an answer?  (You're allowed to answer your own question.)  Thanks.

Comment: @fixer1234 unfortunately, the solution I found was only temporary. Soon-after, even the new drivers I got stopped working. Perhaps I'm not Linux-savvy enough. My ultimate fix was to revert back to Windows (more than just this issue with the printer led to this).

Comment: One weak area for Linux is that some hardware manufacturers keep their drivers proprietary.  So, some brands are harder to get working under Linux.  If you didn't select your hardware for Linux compatibility, it can be frustrating.  Part of the Linux learning curve is Linux and part is getting hardware to work if you own certain brands.  Each OS has its own frustrations.  It's not uncommon for people to give up on Linux and then try it again later when Windows gets on their nerves.  You could also try a different flavor to get your feet wet.  For example, Mint can be easier than Ubuntu.